# Java EE Application to display current server time in seconds

Tags: jakarta-ee, session-bean

Here's the SCCE I've written. I'm completely new to java web application programming which means it's completely possible that I'm missing something. So any advice for a newbie moving forward is really appreciated. I've tried referencing the package name as well with no luck. Is there anything I should be referencing for the Session bean in web.xml? because these files are in the WAR file inside the deployed EAR file. I should note that I'm using java server faces, and EE7.

**GlassFish4 error**
*/index.xhtml @10,78 binding="#{serverSessionBean.time}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'ServerSessionBean'*

**Index Welcome file**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title></title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        The current server time is:
        <h:outputText binding="#{serverSessionBean.time}"/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**ServerSessionBean**

```
package com.incredibleifs;

import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Stateless(description = "A stateless session bean to hold server generic business methods such as getting the date and time")
@Named()
public class ServerSessionBean implements ServerSessionBeanLocal {
    @Override
    public int getTime() {
        return Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The EJB's aren't visible for *expression language (EL)* expressions in **JSF**.
You can use a **JSF** Manage Bean and inject the **EJB** or annotating the **EJB** with the `@Named` annotation makes the **EJB** immediately visible for *expression language (EL)* expressions in **JSF**. 
This `@Named` annotation takes the simple name of the annotated class, puts the first character in lowercase, and exposes it directly to the **JSF** pages. The EJB can be accessed directly, without any backed or managed beans, by the **JSF** pages.

Second, you are using two notations for specifying different types of session beans in the same ejb (`@Singleton`/`@Stateless`).

**Eg.**

**EJB:**

```java
package com.incredibleifs;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;

@Stateless
@Named("serverSessionBean")
public class ServerSessionBean implements ServerSessionBeanLocal {
    @Override
    public int getTime() {
        return Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND);
    }    
}
```

**xhtml file:**

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title></title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        The current server time is:
        <h:outputText binding="#{serverSessionBean.time}"/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**Note** the name is `serverSessionBean` with the first character in lowercase.

See also:

- [The Java EE 7 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/)
- [Contexts and Dependency Injection in Java EE 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/cdi-javaee-bien-225152.html)

Comment: Adding the Named annotation failed, even after removing singleton / stateless annotations. I'm still getting a null reference. I edited my post to point out I'm using java EE 7 -- I'm not sure how different 6 and 7 are either -- though I gather it is different enough.

Comment: @RichardBarker There are differences between Java EE 7 and 6, but in this case applied the answer, see my update maybe help you solve the problem.

Comment: I edited my code to match what I currently have. But it's still failing.

Comment: @RichardBarker To enable cdi you must include the beans.xml file, this is included in the documentation that  I recommended  (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnz.html).

Comment: @Ferderico I did that too. But still the same error is occurring. the session bean is resolving to null. The beans file is in the web-inf directory. I even checked an example I have and found two other files (sun-web.xml, faces.config) and added those. But Its still failing.

Comment: @RichardBarker take a look in this example http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/simplest_possible_jsf_2_ejb, in this not access directly from the jsf page to ejb. I'm not have experience with glassfish, i don't know how glassfish handles the ejbs in the web container.

Comment: Thank you for that link! It helped me fix it. turns out it has to be a managed bean.